# if app device orientation is portrait how to set force landscape only for one view constroller in ios, swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

for my project, device orientation is `portrair`. but only for one view controller when `view did load`, without `rotating` the phone, I want to rotate the view like 'landscape left`. I tried followings . in my view did load,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

    }
```

and I used this method ...

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
      return true
    }
```

but nothing happned. then I use following method too with above methods.

```
 override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
```

then it cause for a crash.  and nothing worked for me. any idea how to do that.

this is my project device orientation settings looks like ...

[image]

how can I do this. hope your help with this.

Comment: check this http://www.jairobjunior.com/blog/2016/03/05/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-in-ios-slash-swift/

Comment: try `func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` in `AppDelegate` then check if your controller is visible

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to [allow all Orientations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYMRX.jpg) in your app settings.

Then set the **"should autorotate"** variable to true il all your viewControllers

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then set the **supportedInterfaceOrientations** depending of your **ViewContoller**

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Landscape

}
```

#### or

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

### For example here I have two viewcontrollers, the view orientation will change when the function viewDidLoad will be called.

```
import UIKit

class PortraitViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Here the viewController will appear in Portrait (Also all subclass of it)
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}

class LandscapeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Here the viewController will appear in Landscape (Also all subclass of it)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Landscape

    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```